# How to install GNOME 40 on Kubuntu 21.04

Tags: gnome, kubuntu

I want to install GNOME 40 on my Kubuntu 40. I have try to search on google but I don't found the way.

Is there any way install GNOME 40 on Kubuntu 21.04?

Comment: the version of GNOME Shell that exists in *hirsute* or 21.04 is 3.38; GNOME 40 was released 24-March-2021 (https://wiki.gnome.org/Forty#Schedule) however the *hirsute* UI freeze was 18-March-2021 (ie. GNOME 40 was too late for 21.04; and it was well after feature freeze https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-schedule/18539/1

Answer (score 4):

Gnome 40 is not officially supported in 21.04.

You can install it with [a `ppa`](https://launchpad.net/%7Eshemgp/+archive/ubuntu/gnome-40), but it is not intended for productive use.
Please carefully read the description of the `PPA` before proceeding.

> WARNING: GNOME 40 is not yet officially supported in Hirsute Hippo. This PPA is just for testing. It breaks sometimes, especially when I'm upgrading the packages.

Also, you need to manually update `mutter` and install `gnome-session`, etc.
You should regard the additional [Installation Instructions after adding the PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eshemgp/+archive/ubuntu/gnome-40).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shemgp/gnome-40
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone doing research on the topic in 2023 like I did – **`task-gnome-desktop` package worked for me on Kubuntu 22.04 to get Gnome DE**:

```
$ sudo apt install task-gnome-desktop
```

It depends on huge bunch of other packages, I installed this on "fairly established" Kubuntu 22.04 installation and I got about 400 new packages. But I'm sure you could remove many of them as they're Gnome apps like Contacts or Calculator.

You need to **set the new desktop environment to be used by default**, I wasn't able to, for example, lock my screen until I did that.

1. Check the current running display manager:

```
$ sudo systemctl status display-manager.service
```

2. Note which DE is on the line starting with `Main PID` --for Kubuntu, it's likely `sddm`. Reconfigure the default manager:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
```

With the command above, you'll be asked interactively to select a new default desktop environment. Select `gdm3` for Gnome.

---

If you're like me doing this mostly just for fun (and to get rid of awesome but unbearably unstable KDE Plasma), **beware of a few things**:

1. You'll have duplicate apps like two calculators, system monitors, and such.
2. You'll need to set your custom keyboard shortcuts anew.
3. Apps from Kubuntu's KDE Plasma will look inconsistent (light theme even if you select dark *Breeze dark* theme for Gnome)