# What is the best way to install Vanilla GNOME Session on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: gnome, gui

I'm not too familiar with GNOME and all. I've seen multiple ways of installing vanilla GNOME 3. How can I install vanilla gnome session without breaking anything ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [need helpto install gnome 40 on kubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335989/need-helpto-install-gnome-40-on-kubuntu-21-04)

Be prepared for a mess, though. The best way to avoid mess is not to change the version of the default DE.

Comment: This is not a question on installing Gnome 40. It is a question on installing vanilla gnome.

Comment: At the duplicate voters: this is *not* about installing Gnome 40 and this is *not* on Kubuntu.

Answer (score 11):

To install vanilla Gnome, i.e., default Gnome with all the standard Gnome applications, install `vanilla-gnome-desktop`:

```
sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop
```

Reboot, and log in to that session. You do that by selecting your name in the log in screen. Before entering the password, click the cog wheel and select the Gnome session.

To only install the default Gnome Shell configuration without any default Gnome applications, install `gnome-session` instead.

If you also wish to change the theming of the login screen from Ubuntu's Yaru to that of Gnome, run `sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3-theme.gresource`.

Comment: Could you explain the relation with `vanilla-gnome-default-settings`? The description of the package doesn't make sense to me, talks about Ubuntu flavor instead of vanilla. Also, `apt purge gnome-session` would rollback to Ubuntu GNOME flavor?

Comment: @PabloBianchi feel free to open a question for this.

Answer (score 7):

I have followed the previous answers but there are still some places that were not changed to vanilla GNOME styles, so here are the full steps I did to make it completely vanilla GNOME.

1. Install `gnome-session`

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-session
   ```
2. Change login screen theme

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3-theme.gresource
   ```
3. Install GNOME default font

   ```
   sudo apt install fonts-cantarell
   ```
4. Install files icon

   ```
   sudo apt install adwaita-icon-theme-full
   ```
5. Go to GNOME tweaks and make sure the fonts are set as follows:

   - Interface Text: Cantarell Regular 11
   - Document Text: Cantarell Regular 11
   - Monospace Text: Monospace Regular 11
   - Legacy Window Titles: Cantarell Regular 11

*Make sure you changed all themes to Adwaita in gnome tweaks and disabled all Ubuntu extensions.*

You may need to reboot or log out and log in in order to see the changes.

Finally, you can download [GNOME 3.38 wallpaper](https://gitlab.gnome.org/bertob/nostalgia/-/tree/master/data/wallpapers/3-38).

Don't forget to change your terminal color scheme to "GNOME light", Firefox theme to "System theme", etc., if you really want it to look vanilla.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Vanilla [GNOME session](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man1/gnome-session.1.html) using below command.

```
sudo apt install gnome-session
```

Comment: This is not a question on installing Gnome 40. It is a question on installing vanilla gnome.