# Upgrade to GNOME 41

Tags: gnome, 21.04

I really want to run GNOME 41 on Ubuntu 21.04. But the problem is that I don't want any residue and the old GNOME as bloat. Is there is any way to do that?

And GNOME 41 on Ubuntu is slower than on Fedora 34 is there any way to speed it up as well?

Comment: You won't be on 21.04 anymore; but you'll need to upgrade much of your system to *impish* which puts you off-topic on this site; as *impish* being a *development* release will only be on-topic after it's release as Ubuntu 21.10 in October 2021.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [need helpto install gnome 40 on kubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335989/need-helpto-install-gnome-40-on-kubuntu-21-04) as GNOME 41 is [not released](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/tags) anywhere.