Failed on Ubuntu 24.10 installation
I am using a Lenovo Thinkbook. Every time I try to install Ubuntu 24.10 with Ventoy, I encounter this error and the installation stop, saying "Something went wrong". I've attempted to re-download the ISO image, but the issue persists. Interestingly, I don't experience this error when installing Kubuntu 24.10. I would appreciate any assistance you can provide.


Possible workaround: install Kubuntu, start it then switch to GNOME: https://askubuntu.com/a/1494068/229365
